# PPTP alternative windows 7

Tags: windows, vpn, pptp

Can't set up a new vpn connection (I only get "Wizard cannot connect" error message) so I'm looking for an alternative client to connect to my pptp vpn server. Anyone got one? I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for PPTP client on Windows there aren't any (at least to my knowledge). I tried this a while back but couldn't find any.

But, there are few that work on *nix platform.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows client won't work it's unlikely any other client will. You should be looking into the underlying problem of why it fails to connect. This is probably to do with settings on your router.  Check out the settings for your router especially in regards to PPTP passthrough or VPN passthrough.